NX workspace: Docker container for React app not running, unable to access localhost
I'm using NX with two apps: one is a NestJS backend (ebook-api) and the other is a ReactJS frontend (ebook-app). I built a Docker image for the ebook-app using the following commands:
docker build -t ebook-app -f apps/ebook-app/Dockerfile .
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 ebook-app

The container is created successfully, but it’s not running. When I try to access the app at http://localhost:3000/, I cannot reach it.
I want to create the Docker image for ebook-app to push it to Docker Hub, but I’m encountering this issue. Here are a few things I've checked:

The container is created, but not running.
There are no error messages in the terminal or logs when I try to start the container.
The NestJS backend (ebook-api) works fine, but ReactJS is facing issues.

docker logs
➜  my-app git:(master) ✗ docker logs 1024f80de425            
The CJS build of Vite's Node API is deprecated. See https://vite.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#vite-cjs-node-api-deprecated for more details.

> nx run ebook-app:serve

> vite serve

The CJS build of Vite's Node API is deprecated. See https://vite.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#vite-cjs-node-api-deprecated for more details.

  VITE v5.4.11  ready in 1309 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:3000/

vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
    root: __dirname,
    cacheDir: '../../node_modules/.vite/apps/ebook-app',
    server: {
        port: 3000,
        host: 'localhost',
    },
    preview: {
        port: 3000,
        host: 'localhost',
    },
    plugins: [react(), nxViteTsPaths(), nxCopyAssetsPlugin(['*.md'])],
    // Uncomment this if you are using workers.
    // worker: {
    //  plugins: [ nxViteTsPaths() ],
    // },
    build: {
        outDir: '../../dist/apps/ebook-app',
        emptyOutDir: true,
        reportCompressedSize: true,
        commonjsOptions: {
            transformMixedEsModules: true,
        },
    },
});


Dockerfile
FROM docker.io/node:lts-alpine

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV PORT=3000

WORKDIR /app

RUN addgroup --system ebook-app && \
          adduser --system -G ebook-app ebook-app

COPY . .

RUN chown -R ebook-app:ebook-app .

RUN npm install

CMD ["npx", "nx", "serve", "ebook-app"]

package.json
...
 "scripts": {
        "start": "nx serve",
        "build": "nx build",
        "test": "nx test",
        "api": "nx serve ebook-api",
        "app": "nx serve ebook-app",
        "dev": "concurrently \"nx serve ebook-api\" \"nx serve ebook-app\""
    }
...

project.json (ebook-app)
....
 "targets": {
    "docker-build": {
       "dependsOn": ["build"],
       "command": "docker build -f apps/ebook-app/Dockerfile . -t ebook-app"
    }
 }

Folder structure


How are you actually running the container?  When you say "the container is created but not running", how do you get to that state?

I ran docker ps to get the list and also verified it via Docker Desktop. I have update docker log and vite.congfig in the post

Apart from the fact that your Dockerfile is terribly inefficient (it seems that you run the container with your app in dev mode with lots of unnecessary stuff carried aboard), can you reach your app from within the container itself (i.e. can you curl localhost:3000 from within docker exec -ti 1024f80de42 /bin/sh)?

If the answer to the above question is positive, you may try and reach the app running in the container from your localhost through the Docker network (find the container's IP by docker inspect 1024f8 and do curl /* container's IP */:3000).

The host: 'localhost' in the Vite configuration is a setting that will make the server unreachable from outside its own container.  Do the settings from running a vite dev server inside a docker container work better for you?

@DavidMaze, working now after host: true. Thanks

The issue was resolved after I updated the vite.config.ts.
Note: The Dockerfile was generated using nx generate setup-docker.
export default defineConfig({
    root: __dirname,
    cacheDir: '../../node_modules/.vite/apps/ebook-app',
    server: {
        port: 3000,
        host: true,
    },
    preview: {
        port: 3000,
        host: true,
    },
});

